# How to call power bi api using power bi desktop to access access content from Power BI service

Tags: api, powerbi

Do you know how to call power bi api using Power BI Desktop to access access content from Power BI Service. I want to get number of workspaces and number of Reports, dataset Last Refresh time.

Answer (score 0):

here is option on home ribbon, you can access all your datasets on Power Bi Service within Power Bi Desktop from here
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3pFD.png)

hope this will help (i noticed your question is 11 months old and may be you already have find the answer)

Comment: This is not an answer to OP's question. He wants to create a report from the Power BI Service data (i.e. the list of workspaces, published reports, execution datetimes, etc.), not the from Power BI datasets.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to use the Power BI REST API Connector from Github ([link](https://github.com/migueesc123/PowerBIRESTAPI)). Then you can connect to the service directly from PBI Desktop.

The hard way is to register an app into AAD and then use the credentials to connect to the API, as described in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjzmz0BNN_g)